# IIS generate machine key by command line for Jenkins

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, jenkins

We have a load balanced environment with Jenkins where the commits are automatically deployed. Since we are using SignalR in order to work we have to have the same machine key in all the servers in the farm. We can do it by manually going into IIS Manager and generate the key which will be included in the web.config file. But since we are using Jenkins for automatic deploy we need this also to be automatic. I tried to find a way to do this via command line but couldn't find any resources. Is there a way to generate machine keys and add it to the web.config so all the process will be automatic?

Answer (score 4):

You can generate the machine key via command line using powershell. Microsoft provide this code and can be found here (https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors#bookmark-appendixa)

```
function Generate-MachineKey {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [ValidateSet("AES", "DES", "3DES")]
    [string]$decryptionAlgorithm = 'AES',
    [ValidateSet("MD5", "SHA1", "HMACSHA256", "HMACSHA384", "HMACSHA512")]
    [string]$validationAlgorithm = 'HMACSHA256'
  )
  process {
    function BinaryToHex {
        [CmdLetBinding()]
        param($bytes)
        process {
            $builder = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
            foreach ($b in $bytes) {
              $builder = $builder.AppendFormat([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", $b)
            }
            $builder
        }
    }
    switch ($decryptionAlgorithm) {
      "AES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider }
      "DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider }
      "3DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider }
    }
    $decryptionObject.GenerateKey()
    $decryptionKey = BinaryToHex($decryptionObject.Key)
    $decryptionObject.Dispose()
    switch ($validationAlgorithm) {
      "MD5" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACMD5 }
      "SHA1" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 }
      "HMACSHA256" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 }
      "HMACSHA385" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA384 }
      "HMACSHA512" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512 }
    }
    $validationKey = BinaryToHex($validationObject.Key)
    $validationObject.Dispose()
    [string]::Format([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
      "<machineKey decryption=`"{0}`" decryptionKey=`"{1}`" validation=`"{2}`" validationKey=`"{3}`" />",
      $decryptionAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $decryptionKey,
      $validationAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $validationKey)
  }
}
```

This returns the machine key as a string. You can then apply that to the web.config file via powershell too. The following code will either add it or replace it

```
function ApplyMachineKeyToWebConfigs($machineKey)
{
    $webConfig = (Get-Content $webConfigPath) -as [Xml]

    if($webConfig.configuration["system.web"].machineKey)
    {
        $webConfig.configuration["system.web"].ReplaceChild($webConfig.ImportNode($machineKey.machineKey, $true), $webConfig.configuration["system.web"].machineKey)
    }
    else 
    {
        $webConfig.configuration["system.web"].AppendChild($webConfig.ImportNode($machineKey.machineKey, $true))
    }

    $webConfig.save($webConfigPath)
}
```

Where `$webConfigPath` is the path to the web config file on the server.
You will need to generate the machine key on the server itself so we can run these remotely via your CI on jenkins. If you create a powershell script combining the functions (called `GenerateMachineKey.ps1`):

```
[xml]$machineKey = Generate-MachineKey
ApplyMachineKeyToWebConfigs $machineKey
```

Passing in the web.config path you then run it like so:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <ipAddress or computer name> -FilePath GenerateMachineKey.ps1 -ArgumentList c:\DeployedApps\YourWebsite\Web.config -credential $Credentials
```

You need to set up credentials to invoke the command which can be achieved with the following commands:

```
$Username = 'admin'
$Password = 'password'
$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePass
```

You can now fully automate setting your IIS machine key via jenkins or any other CI platform using these powershell scripts